# Site aliases: Use a different PHP path on remote

Tags: drush

#### The Problem:

For reasons I'm not gonna get into, the path to my php executable is ***NOT*** `/usr/bin/php` but is instead something else (let's say it's `/local/path/to/php`).

My staging and production servers ***do*** use `/usr/bin/php`, however; Moreover, the non-standard php path doesn't exist on those servers.

The problem is that whenever I run a Drush command for a remote site, I get an error:

```
$ drush @mysite.remote status
bash: /local/path/to/php: No such file or directory
```

Since `/local/path/to/php` *definitely* exists on my local machine (or else my local sites wouldn't work and drush would fail) I can only assume that error is coming from the remote server.

I know I can pass `--php=/usr/bin/php` to Drush, but there are some less Drupal-savvy devs on my team, so I want to get it configured for them so they don't have to think about it.

I also know about the `$DRUSH_PHP` environment variable, but setting that to `/usr/bin/php` breaks drush on my dev machine entirely, so that's not an option either.  It just straight-up breaks Drush.

#### The Question:

Is there a way to configure my remote aliases to use a specific path to PHP that is different to my local machine's PHP path?  (And why is a remote server trying to use a local path to PHP in the first place?)

If not, what workarounds are there? (I'm hoping I won't have to create a symlink at `/non/standard/php` to `/usr/bin/php` on my servers, because that feels fragile and hack-ish, but if there are no alternatives, it'll have to do.)

---

Drush 7.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **example.aliases.drushrc.php**:

> Although most aliases will contain only a few options, a number
>   of settings that are commonly used appear below:

...

> 'php': path to custom php interpreter. Windows support limited to Cygwin.

So try somtehing like:

```
$aliases['example'] = array(
  'uri' => 'example.com',
  'root' => '/var/www/example.com',
  'remote-host' => 'www.example.com',
  'remote-user' => 'user',
  'php' => '/path/to/php/on/the/server'
);
```

You could try that. If this doesn't work I would suggest to update your drush version (locally and on the server) and try again, before doing any strange symlinking on the server.

Comment: Yep, this worked like a charm.  I went up and down that example file I thought a million times and couldn't find anything about PHP, so I don't know how I missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: any idea how to do this in Drush 9?